# Adding element at top of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to add an element to a container div before existing elements. I have attempted to this three different ways and couldn't

Method 1

`$('.channel:first',$('#scroll_5')).before(print_nav);`

Method 2

`$('.channel:eq(0)',$('#scroll_5')).before(print_nav);`

Method 3

```
$('.channel',$('#scroll_5')).each(function () {
    $(this).before(print_nav);
    return false;
});
```

The container div is `scroll_5` and has elements with the class `channel`.  I want to add a new channel at the top.  What is the right way to do that?

Comment: Add jQuery tag, I was gonna give you a vanilla Javascript solution. Guess not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#scroll_5').prepend(print_nav);
```

See http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Or:

```
$(print_nav).prependTo('#scroll_5');
```

See http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/

Comment: The real bug was unrelated.  But `prepend` is the way to add that element at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
$("#scroll_5").prepend("<div />");
```